# I changed the functional component containing the FORMIK to the class component and got errors. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have functional components that contains formik:

```
const SignupForm = () => {

    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
          /....
      },
        validateOnBlur: false, 
        validateOnchange: false,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({    
          /.....
      }),   
      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              /.....
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);   
          } 
      },  
    });

   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
      /....
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>       
   </form>
   );
};
```

but I needed to change this component to class, and I did:

```
class SignupForm extends React.Component {

    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
          /....
      },
        validateOnBlur: false, 
        validateOnchange: false,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({    
          /....
      }),   
      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              /.....
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);   
          } 
      },  
    });
  render() {  
   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
      /.....
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>       
   </form>
   );
  }
};
```

and I got errors:

```
./src/components/Signup/SignupForms.js
  Line 11:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   9 | class SignupForm extends React.Component {
  10 |  
> 11 |     const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
     |           ^         
  12 |       initialValues: {
  13 |           username: '',
  14 |           password: '',
```

Error screenshot

[image: screenshot error]

How to fix this error? Please help me write a class component so that there are no errors.

Comment: Is `useFormik` a react hook? If so it can't work in class-based component. JS classes don't have class `const`'s either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use hooks in Class components.

There is a library (https://github.com/salvoravida/react-universal-hooks) that will let you, but it isn't considered a best practice to mix the two. The React team made that restriction to make things stay sane.

You'll have to use the [withFormik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik) higher-order component or their [`<Formik />`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik) Component which uses render props instead.

Here's an example I put together that uses their render props component as it was pretty straightforward to convert.

```
class SignupForm extends React.Component {


    render() {
        const formikProps = {
            initialValues: {
                //....
            },
            validateOnBlur: false,
            validateOnchange: false,
            validationSchema: yup.object().shape({
                //....
            }),
            onSubmit: async (formValues, { setSubmitting }) => {
                console.log('submit', formValues);
                setSubmitting(true);
                try {
                    ///.....
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
            },
        };
        return (
            <Formik {...formikProps} >
                {props =>
                    (<form className="fform" onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                        {/*/.....*/}
                        <button type="submit" disabled={props.isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>
                    </form>)}
            </Formik>
        );
    }
};
```

Here's the component chagned to using a class instead of hooks https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dew-ey8o9. Everything aside from the data call works itself (405 error). The data call does get all the items from the form which is the important part.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried to fix as you advised but in that case nothing works...Could you write what you wrote in answer to my sandbox?
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mountain-9zbbz 
filename Signupform.js. Also in sandbox in folder public/data I created file data.json because I use local server in my computer and cannot transfer data from the local server to the sandbox

Comment: Okay, changes are made. Out of curiosity, why are you switching *from* hooks? Usually it's the other way around.